# How do I make a context sensitive hotkey that depends on whether CapsLock is toggled?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to autoreplace `mn` for my name only if `CapsLock` is toggled.

I have tried many things but I haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code? What were the error messages, if any?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the following keywords:

- `#HotIf [Expression]`
  This keyword creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings depending of the evaluation of `Expression`.
  You should check the Docs to get a better understanding, but as a general guideline, this directive affects the behaviour of the hotkeys defined after it, unless specified otherwise.
- `GetKeyState(KeyName, [Mode])`
  You should check the Docs in order to adapt it to your script, but I can give you some general guidelines from the information given.

  - The `Mode` parameter should be set to `"T"`, since you want to retrieve the toggle state of the key.
  - `Keyname` should be set to `CapsLock`.

In other words, your script should look like this:

```
#HotIf GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
::mn::My Name
```

Without any more context, this is all I can do. As @Jannick Breunis has already mentioned, it is a good practice to show what you have tried (by providing your own code snippets, or error messages, if any), and ellaborate more on the desired behaviour, since you might want to make the Hotstring trigger without having to press `Space` after typing `mn`.
Do also notice that the Hotstring's behaviour is case insensitive. This is specially important since having CapsLock on would mean you would be typing `MN` to trigger the Hotstring.
Check the Docs for more detailed Hotstring triggering behaviour (I am not sure why would you want to have to hold `Shift` while typing `mn` with `CapsLock` toggled, but you are free to do it).